# При выводе двухмерного массива возникает ошибка (I@12a3a380) для всех элементов массива

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


public class massiv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] myArray = new int[5][5];
    int [] sum = new int [5];
    int sumo = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = rand.nextInt(9);
        }
    }

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            sum[i] += myArray[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sumo += sum[i];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray) );

    }
}
```

Comment: почему Вы решили что это ошибка?

Comment: Вам надо выводить точно также, как вы и заполняете, в 2 циклах `for`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Это не ошибка, но хочу в нормальном формате вывод

Answer (score 1):

То что Вы видите в в выводе это вывод стандартного метода `toString()` от массива, чтобы вывести содержимое вложенных массивов, воспользуйтесь методом [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[][] myArray = new int[5][5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        myArray[i][j] = rand.nextInt(9);
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
```